# boost::asio, specify source IP of a connection

Tags: c++, boost, ip, boost-asio

My server has two public IPs, which is running a client program that connects and download some data from a target server, and I want to create, for example, 10 TCP connections from my first IP, and another 10 TCP connections from my second IP, to download in parallel 20 different files.

How could I specify the source IP of each connection using `boost::asio` on a client program, once the server IP has been resolved?

Comment: You can *bind* a socket to a specific interface.

Comment: This is not related to boost or asio. It's basic network stack. If you only wonder how to translate it to boost using asio, you should share the code you have tried.

Comment: @sehe I don't think it is a "network stack" question. Anyway, I don't know too much about how the network stack truly work. What I've seen in the documentation, is that, to specify a local_endpoint, I have to specify also the port, and I want the port is automatically specified. The point is, that I have a paid account to proxymesh, which has a limit of 10 connection per client_ip/proxy_ip. What I'm looking for actually is how to create 10 connections per each client IP to a same proxy-ip to have a total of 20 parallel connections.

Comment: @sehe So far, I just `resolve` the remote_endpoint and `async_connect` to it, letting the local_endpoint being automatically decided, and I'm trying to googling and browse the boost::asio reference to find how to specify that, without success so far (for the server side is of course easier to find answers but I don't know exactly if I'm required to bound the socket first when in the client side).